# how to create custom module in magento2 to add customer attribute?

Tags: magento2

While adding customer attribute to magento2 admin will not save automatically. The attribute is displayed in the account section. But could not save any value.Please help me tho resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple module to install custom attribute for customer section.
You have to assign customer group and attribute set. othervise it does not save in the db.

Step 1: registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_WholesalerCustomer',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 2:Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_WholesalerCustomer" setup_version="1.0.3"/>
</config>
```

Step3 :installData.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\WholesalerCustomer\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;


    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig,AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_currency',
            [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Customer Currency',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true, 
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'source' => 'Test\WholesalerCustomer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Currency',
                    'system' => 0,
                    'sort_order' => 90,
                    'position' => 90,

                ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_company',
            [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Company of wholesalers',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true, 
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,

                    'system' => 0,
                    'sort_order' => 80,
                    'position' => 80,

                ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_price_limit',
            [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Credit limit for Ambassador Group B customers',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true, 
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,

                    'system' => 0,


                ]);

        $customerCurrencyAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_currency')->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','checkout_register'],
    ]);
        $customerCurrencyAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','checkout_register']

        );
        $customerCurrencyAttribute->save();
        $customerCompanyAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_company')->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','checkout_register'],
    ]);
        $customerCompanyAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','checkout_register']

        );
        $customerCompanyAttribute->save();
        $customerPriceLimitAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_price_limit')->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','checkout_register'],
    ]);
        $customerPriceLimitAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','checkout_register']

        );
        $customerPriceLimitAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

Source.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\WholesalerCustomer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;

class Currency extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();


        $storeObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager')->getStore();
        $codes = $storeObj->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true);
        $this->_options = array(array('value' =>'' ,'label'=> '--Please Select--'));
        if (is_array($codes) && count($codes) >= 1) {
            foreach ($codes as $code) {


                $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => $code,
                    'label' => $code
            );

            }
        }
        //array_unshift($this->_options,'--Please Select--'); 

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```